# Redgate failing to compare schema between different versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, redgate, red-gate-ants, red-gate-sql-prompt, red-gate-data-compare

I am trying to compare the data and schema using SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare (version 10.2).

The databases I am working with are in versions 2014 and 2016 of SQL Server.

I am getting this error message.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening - could it be because the Redgate version I have is not compatible with the latter SQL Server 2016 version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved upon upgrading ...